# How to set a Foundation tooltip in a ng-repeat loop?

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-foundation

I'm trying to display a value in a table cell, and then show a tooltip which is a function of that value.

My test block of HTML looks like

```
<tr ng-repeat="btcAsk in latestAsksFromBcId | limitTo:10">
    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td><span data-tooltip class="has-tip" title="{{btcAsk.btcValue}}">{{btcAsk.btcValue}}</span></td>
    <td running-total currIndex="{{$index}}">{{btcAsk.btcAmnt}}</td>
    <td currency-convert idrVal="{{(btcAsk.btcValue * btcAsk.btcAmnt).toFixed(2)}}"></td>
</tr>
```

In the second table cell(td) the tooltip shows, but is blank. Even though the same value between the span tags displays properly.

So I took a different approach (shown in the 4th table cell) and thought I'd make a custom directive.

```
bitcoinApp.directive("currencyConvert", function(CurrencyConversions) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        idrval: '@'
    },
    template: '<span data-tooltip class="has-tip" title="USD val">{{idrval}}</span>'
  };
});
```

The template is inserted and yet this shows no tooltip.. not even the hardcoded text in the title.

My script includes are

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.2.3/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.2.3/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.18/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.8.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

Also, I notice there is http://madmimi.github.io/angular-foundation/ but not sure if it's relevant to why this is not working as expected?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using AngularUI Bootstrap library for tooltip directive ? or the foundation . Please clarify.

Comment: Have you tried tooltip="See? Now click away..."

Comment: I'm using Foundation. I've updated my post to show the script tags for external libraries.